# inputting values into an array and printing the total value in the command prompt

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create an array that holds prices that the user inputs into the command prompt.
This is what I have so far

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Chapter6._2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int price;
            int[] pricesList = new int[9];
            Write("Enter price 1: ");
            price = Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Also how would I create a loop to where it asks for the price of an item 10 times but goes something like this...

```
"Enter price 1: < user input price >" 
"Enter price 2: < user input price >"
"Enter price 3: < user input price >"
```

and etc...Hopefully that makes sense.

Basically with these 2 questions I have asked, how would I create a loop where the program asks the user for prices 10 times, and stores the prices in an array and prints the total of all of the prices entered into the program at the end.

Comment: You need to use for loop to repeat the message display and user input.

Comment: I won't do your homework for you but ill give some hints. Look up `for loop in C#`. Then look up `arrays in c#`. Those two concepts are all you need to accomplish this.

Comment: @TheBatman I was hoping that you weren't going to for me. I just wanted some pointers and what I should do to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **for loop**, cycling many times as your array *length*. Each iteration will ask the user for the Nth price, store it in the Nth position of the array and add the price to some "sum" variable. Also maybe you want to check [System.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.8) class.

This is as far I can go without doing your homework for you.

Please read this before asking more school related stuff:
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Think of using a for loop. Your condition should be like `i <= pricesList.Length`
You can ask for user input as something like this: `Console.WriteLine("Enter price {0}", i);` or `Console.WriteLine("Enter price {0}", i+1);` if you want to start with 1 and not 0.

See array loops here [C# arrays](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/arrays/)